# UIPopoverController change view

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, storyboard, uipopovercontroller

I want to change view in my UIPopoverController.

I have :

```
if (popoverController == nil) {
        UIStoryboard * storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard" bundle:nil];
        Help *d = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Help"];
        //Help *d = [[Help alloc]initWithNibName:@"Help" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
        UIPopoverController *popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:d];
        popover.delegate = self;

        popoverController = popover;

    }

CGRect popoverRect = [self.view convertRect:[helpBtn frame] fromView:[helpBtn superview]];

popoverRect.size.width = MIN(popoverRect.size.width, 100); 
[popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:popoverRect inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

and it load first view, but on the first view I have button and whit it I want to change viewcontroller in storyboard.

But when I do that it opens new view as fullscreen view not as UIPopoverController.

Thanks for help

Marko

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several solutions.

The better one is to have different **views** managed by your view controller rather than changing the **view controller**. It seems easier.

You could also wrap your view controller inside a **navigation controller** and then push and pop or present modally.

Finally, you could try to dismiss / destroy your popover and make a **new** one with the other view controller, but you would have to fiddle with the animations to make that look good.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please mark the answer with the check mark if it helped you.